# Circle - finding the equation

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, circles

Question:
Find the equation of a circle whose center is in the first quadrant; touches the x-axis at (4,0) and makes an intercept of length 6 units on the y-axis.

I am getting a faint idea where to start on this question, but the method turns out to be very long. I'm pretty sure that there's a small hint that will make the question much easier to solve? Please help!

Comment: By "touches" do they mean tangent? By "makes an intercept of length 6 units on the y-axis" mean just that (0, 6) is a point of the circle?

Comment: I am interpreting that the $y$-axis cuts the circle in a chord of length $6$. I recommend drawing a diagram. For a clue show that the centre is on the line $x=4$ and drop a perpendicular from the centre to the $y$-axis.

Comment: Well there was no figure given. @PaulSundheim Touches mean tangent. And making an intercept of length 6 units would mean that the two intercepts are at a distance of 6 units.

Comment: You can always draw your own diagram - which can be very useful for a problem like this, even if it is only approximate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $O$ be the center of the circle, and let $A,B$ be the intersection points between the circle and $y$-axis. Also, let $M$ be the middle point of the line segment $AB$.

Then, letting $r$ be the radius, consider a right triangle $OMA$ with $$OA=r,\ OM=4,\  AM=6/2=3.$$

You'll get $r^2=3^2+4^2$ with the center $(4,r)$.

Hence, you'll get $r=5$. So, the answer is $(x-4)^2+(y-5)^2=25$.

Comment: @Gummybears: I hope this helps.

Comment: @Gummybears: Yes, it's the radius. It is the same as the length of a line segment from the center of the circle to $y$-axis. You'll see this if you draw pictures.

Comment: Never mind. Sorry, I got mixed up a bit. Thank you! I knew there had to be an easier way. I was just unable to see the triangle being formed.

Comment: @Gummybears: You are welcome!

Comment: Just hate the fact that I was unable to see this on my own :(

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you're trying to solve. So you want to find the equation of a circle such that the circle is sitting tangent to the x-axis at $\left(4,0\right)$ and its two intercepts of the y-axis must result in a line of length $6$ between them. In other words, you need to know its radius so that you can find the center and therefore its equation. Well, you already have the x-value, $4$, so no need to worry about that. To find the radius you'll need to draw a triangle connecting the center of your proposed circle to both of the y-intercepts. From there you know the length of the distance between them to be $6$, and the height of that triangle to be $4$ units. Then by simply dividing $6$ in two you arrive at one of the two triangle's bases, and then the Pythagorean theorem allows you to arrive at the missing side's length, which is the radius of your circle:

$$ 3^2+4^2=r^2\implies{r}=\sqrt{25}=\boxed{5} $$

So the equation of your circle is thus

$$ 25=\left(x-4\right)^2+\left(y-5\right)^2 $$

Just drew a quick picture, I hope I'm right...double check me.

Comment: Nope, actually I assumed it to be $r$ and then used half the distance between the chord connecting the two y-intercepts and the Pythagorean theorem to determine r. Graph the equations formed by this and you will see that I am right: $$y=\sqrt{25-\left(x-4\right)^2}+5,y=-\sqrt{25-\left(x-4\right)^2}+5$$

Comment: Yes I saw that the moment after I posted my comment. Haha that's why I deleted it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! I went back and double checked myself too

Answer (score 0):

**A start:** Draw a picture. The centre of the circle is $(4,a)$ for an as yet unknown positive $a$ and the radius is $a$. So the circle has equation $\dots$.

In the equation, set $x=0$. The two $y$-values differ by $6$.

**Remark:** The above is an analytic geometry approach. There is a much cleaner way using just basic geometry.

Comment: I tried that. I am getting two equations with two variables, but solving it is becoming a problem...

Comment: The equation simplifies to $(x-4)^2+y^2-2ay=0$. Setting $x=0$ we get $y^2-2ay+16=0$. This has solutions $y=a\pm\sqrt{a^2-16}$ (Quadratic Formula). The difference is $2\sqrt{a^2-16}$. This is $6$, so $\sqrt{a^2-16}=9$. Over! There are nicer more geometric approaches, but I guessed you are doing this in an analytic geometry context.

Comment: I don't think it really matters how I do it if I get the answer? I liked the answers that the others gave me. Btw, I tried that method but solving it was getting a bit difficult. I would have been able, but I knew there would be an easier method.

Comment: Yes, just draw a picture. Draw a line through the centre parallel to the $x$-axis, meeting the $y$-axis at $M$. By symmetry this $M$ is halfway between the $y$-intercepts. Then easy Pythagorean Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Your first two requirements basically say that if $r$ is the radius of the circle then its center is at the point $(4,r)$ (and also that $r>0$). We put this into the standard equation of a circle and get
$${(x - 4)^2} + {(y - r)^2} = {r^2} $$

The intercept requirement means that the point $(0,6)$ is on the circle: substituting we get
$${(0 - 4)^2} + {(6 - r)^2} = {r^2}$$

Solving, we get a linear equation (the $r^2$'s cancel) which solves to
$$r=\frac{{13}}{3}$$

Substituting that into our original equation,

$${(x - 4)^2} + {(y - \frac{{13}}{3})^2} = \frac{{169}}{9}$$

You can multiply both sides by 9 and do other operations if you prefer another form for the equation.

Comment: No. The fact that it makes an intercept of length 6 units means that the y-axis cuts a chord of length 6 units on the circle.

Comment: Oh, I see. I wondered if there was another interpretation to what you wrote. Oh, well.